# How to Stop WSO2 ESB 4.0.3

Tags: java, linux, wso2, wso2-esb

I have started the WSO2 ESB server with ./wso2server.sh , but there is no script to stop the server ?

Can anybody tell the command to stop the server ?

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: I mean I need a command promt command for shutting down wso2

Comment: give me the source of this script and il tell you, otherwise this is way tomuch hassle

Answer (score 5):

If you have started the server using ./wso2server.sh then you can stop the server by pressing Ctrl and c keys together on the console, it will simply kill the server.

If you have started using ./wso2server.sh --start or ./deamon.sh start then you can kill the server using the commands ./wso2server.sh --stop or ./deamon.sh stop.

Answer (score 3):

`./wso2server.sh --stop` or `./daemon.sh stop`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, pressing CTRL + C in the terminal you started the server would do.

If it's not possible for you, then do the following.

Enter the command `ps ax | grep wso2esb`

This will list the set of processes started that has the text wso2esb. Unless you opened several esb instances, there will be one process that would like the following [1]. There, the first number refers to the process id.

So, enter following command to **gracefully** shutdown the esb.

`kill <process-id>`

You may force the shutdown by sending signal `kill` (`-9`) like follows if you need to.

`kill -9 <process-id>`

As you may have noticed, the kill command is a native program that comes with most linux distros, not a wso2 provided one.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the server,

- If you have started the server using ./wso2server.sh then you can stop the   server by pressing Ctrl+C in the command window
- If you have started using ./wso2server.sh --start then stop using ./wso2server.sh --stop
- If you have started using ./deamon.sh start use ./deamon.sh stop
- clicking the Shutdown/Restart link in the navigation pane in the Management Console works well for all..

Answer (score 1):

On Management-Console, we can shutdown or Restart

[image: On management console]

On management console we can shutdown / Restart

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread... but I since I arrived here with the same question, I may as well post the answer I found for future users.

Another way to shut down the wso2 server is through the online admin console. Once the server is running, simply navigate in your browser to

```
https://localhost:9443/carbon
```

Log into the server's admin page using the default username and password, "admin" for both. Then scroll to the bottom of the page and select "shutdown/restart" and select "graceful shutdown" from the menu.